# is the whole Flutter code executed inside MainActivity extending FlutterActivity?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

We give runApp(MyApp()) inside void main() of main.dart file.

My doubt is after FlutterActivity is extended to MainActivity. Will this MainActivity now initialize FlutterEngine and execute the whole FlutterEngine inside the MainActivity itself.

Like the whole Flutter App itself runs inside a single MainActivity or is there any process under hood?

Can anybody explain in detail to an Android Developer trying to understand the magic of how Flutter runs in Android.

P.S : I came to know that FlutterEngine is responsible for rendering ui and is the runtime environment for the whole dart code i.e. flutter app

Comment: I would think it all runs on the same process. There's definitely only one Activity. Although this suggests that you can start other processes https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/background-processes but maybe the word "process" is used more loosely here. And I'm also not sure if there are any background processes run by Flutter by default